# Unable to figure out what this c syntax is

Tags: c, variable-declaration

I hate asking syntax questions like this, but I've not been able to find an answer through searching. I'm unsure as to what each of these variable declarations means. My best guess for the 3rd was that it's taking the logical and of the address of the label checkpoint and the inverse of the size of the page, casting it as an unsigned long, then recasting it as a void pointer. The code is from here: http://nmav.gnutls.org/2011/12/self-modifying-code-using-gcc.html

```
int (*my_printf) (const char *format, ...);
void (*my_exit) (int);
void *page =
  (void *) ((unsigned long) (&&checkpoint) &
    ~(getpagesize() - 1));
```

Thanks!

Comment: The first two are function pointers

Comment: Yes that is exactly what it is doing. Not sure why you needed to ask this. All you did was state in words what the expression says.

Comment: Note that "address of label" (`&&checkpoint`, here) is a GNU C extension, and may not work in other compilers.

Answer (score 5):

`my_printf` is a pointer for a function returning an int, and which takes a char pointer argument and a variable list of others.

`my_exit` is a pointer to a function with no return value, taking one int argument.

`page` is a pointer to some unspecified type. It is assigned the value of an expression that shouldn't compile, because `&&` is a binary operator and has no left operand, and unary address-of-address is meaningless. The `& ~(getpagesize() - 1)` bit masks off the low-order bits of what presumably is meant to be an address, which would then point to the beginning of a page.

The unary `&&` is a GNU C extension that takes the address of a (goto) label, so this construction basically gets the address of the start of the code page containing that label. This is very compiler- and OS-specific stuff, and not really part of the C language.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are function pointers that are compatible with `printf` and `exit`, respectively. E.g. you can do:

```
my_exit = exit;
my_exit(3);
```

and it would be equivalent to calling `exit(3)`.

Your guess about the third is correct. It's depending on the fact that page size will always be a power of 2. Therefore, `pagesize-1` will have a binary pattern that's all 1's in the low-order bits, all 0's in the high-order bits.  Inverting it reverses those bits. This can be used as a bit mask with an address to return the address of the beginning of the page that the address points to. It then sets `page` to the beginning of the page containing `checkpoint`.

Comment: Thanks so much. Why do they make page a void* though, instead of leaving it as an unsigned long? Also, why does that bitmask work to return the beginning of the page? Say, for example, the page size is 8, and the address of checkpoint is 00100000. The inverse of pagesize-1 would be 1111000. The & would be 00100000. Why would this necessarily be the start of the page containing checkpoint? Couldn't it also start at 00011111, for example, and still maintain a pagesize of 8 while containing checkpoint?

Answer (score 0):

`int (*my_printf) (const char *format, ...);` declares a function pointer that returns an int, and takes a c style string as a first parameter, with a variable number of arguments after the format parameter.

`void (*my_exit) (int);` declares a function pointer that doesn't return anything, but takes an int.

`void *page = (void *) ((unsigned long) (&&checkpoint) & ~(getpagesize() - 1));` declares a generic pointer that is equivalent to the address of the pointer to `checkpoint` masked with the page size minus one.